RemoteApp Allow only client Folders
I've been searching a lot online and I can not find the answer I am looking for. I have an RDS server running our software as a remoteApp. Everything works really well, but when the user selects a file to import into the software the folder select opens on their user on the server.
How can I change this that all folder browsing should go directly to the client folders instead of the server.
I have a Gpo protecting the server but I can't explain to every user that they should first find their C drive in the menu and continue to their own folders.
I am running ms Server 2022.
I am no expert in all of this and I really hope my question makes sense. Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated!
